# How to host Angular 6 application in AWS serverless architecture along with domain and SSL?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-serverless

Our back end Apis are written in AWS serverless architecture, and we are able to access Database from local system and application working properly, But we are no idea about host application on a domain.

Answer (score 1):

This is the architecture that you would normally follow to host angular app along with serverless backend:

1. Lambda will be used to host the back-end of your application. You can use SAM (serverless application model) or NodeJS Serverless framework to package and deploy the backend.
2. For front end i.e. Angular, you'll use S3 to host the static files for angular. You'll serve the static files using AWS CloudFront.
3. For SSL, you'll AWS Certificate Manager (ACM). You'll be able to use SSL certificates hosted on ACM with CloudFront.
4. For Databases, you can either use RDS (relation) or DynamoDB (non-relational).

Comment: My backend already mounts on AWS Lambda and no issues in backend deployment, but my front end on angular which is a completely dynamic manner, each time I am unable to move my files to s3.

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic manner? If you mean, it's difficult to move files manually to S3 then you can setup some pipeline to automate moving files to S3.

Comment: Yes you came to point thanks, how to set pipeline that each time pushed into git will become new build and go to S3

Comment: Sure. So Here's how you'll do it. Setup a CI tool such as Jenkins, Poll Git for changes in Jenkins job, it will trigger Jenkins job whenever changes occur, build angular files in Jenkins job and finally use jenkins job to upload it to S3. 
You can use AWS Codepipeline as well.

Comment: Let me know if there's anything you don't understand.

Comment: @ShyamKumarNallaguntla you can use git CD for the same.